# What made the Ancient One do this in Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* Banner travels to

> New York to get the Time Stone from the Ancient One.

Initially he seems like he will be unsuccessful until

> He tells her that Strange has already given up the Time Stone to Thanos, at this point the Ancient One has a change of heart, says something to her self and then hands over the Time Stone.

Why did this happen, what made her change her mind?

Comment: [Cross site dupe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/100333/27415), though the title phrasing is different.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The Ancient One recognises that Strange is meant to be "the best of us" and after having been told Strange gave it up willingly he must have had a reason for it. Therefore, she is trusting in Strange, and so Bruce, that whatever is happening, is happening for a reason and gives him the Time Stone per Strange's plan.

She needn't have known what Strange's plan actually is, he could have looked forward to work out how to win or might be playing a long game with time travel or something else. She doesn't need to know the actual plan just that it's Strange's and that's enough for her to trust his judgement.

> **Bruce:** Then, why the hell did Strange give it away?
>
> **Ancient One:** What did you say?
>
> **Bruce:** Strange, he gave it away. He gave it to Thanos.
>
> **Ancient One:** Willingly?
>
> **Bruce:** Yes.
>
> **Ancient One:** ...Why?
>
> **Bruce:** I have no idea. Maybe he made a mistake.
>
> **Ancient One:** Or I did. Strange is meant to be the best of us.
>
> **Bruce:** So he must have done it for a reason.
>
> **Ancient One:** I fear you might be right.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Comment: The Line "or I did" is interesting, If she was talking about that moment and not handing the stone over i would have thought she said "or I am". also why does she fear he might be right? That is what is confusing me the most.

Comment: @RichardC _"or I did"_ meaning _"or I made a mistake by not giving you the Stone straight away"_ and _"I fear you may be right"_ is just an expression, she believes he may be right that Strange had a reason to hand the Stone over willingly and that is why she gives it over.

Comment: @RichardC I took it to mean "Or maybe I made a mistake in thinking he was the best of us".  She knows that the version of herself in the "main" (from our perspective) timeline already decided to trust Strange (train him, give him the stone, etc.), and presumably she herself in that timeline has also decided to do so. So either both versions have made a mistake, or she should give the stone to Banner.

Comment: @RichardC There are two possible mistakes she could be making.  (1) believing that she should never give up the stone.  (2) believing that Strange will be the best of us.  As for being afraid that he did it for a (good) reason: imagine someone you know gave away a nuclear bomb to a maniac.  If that was the *best possible choice* by someone *honestly trying to save human life on the planet*, think how bad the situation must be?

Comment: @Acccumulation That's what I think, and makes by _far_ the most sense compared to theories about the statement being about the stone in that moment.  It ties directly in with her hesitation to train him back during _Doctor Strange_.

Comment: @Acccumulation Except that if that was the intended meaning, she wouldn't have given the stone to Bruce. You don't say "Hm, maybe I shouldn't have trusted that guy!" and then give him the cosmic keystone.

Comment: @Luaan though if you did already in an alternate timeline it wouldn't actually matter, because *he's already got the stone*. So he could just do his crazy and then come for it somewhere else.

Comment: @Luaan One can acknowledge alternative hypotheses without concluding that they are true.

Answer (score 2):

I believe she realizes that Doctor Strange would not have handed over the Stone without a fight unless he had very good reason to. She concludes that he either scanned the timelines to work out the best course of action to follow or she chooses to trust his judgement on the matter.